# Watson Conversation: How to maintain position in dialog flow for additional user input

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

The use case I'm trying to implement is as follows:

1. User asks for a portion of a web page to be read aloud, e.g., "read instructions", "read background", "play notes", etc. (Watson STT)
2. STT request passed to Conversation (via app server) and interpreted; response indicates the section type (leaving out for now a prompt if the section type was incorrect)
3. App server responds to user by playing an audio (Watson TTS) of the requested section
4. User asks to pause, stop, continue or replay the selected section (STT)

It's step #4 that I'm having problems with.  If the request is pause, stop or continue then those could presumably be handled by a separate #intent and the app server just passes a command to the `<audio>` control accordingly.  However, if the request is replay, then I need to know what section type was originally requested.  I have a feeling that the app server needs to set the context to make this work but I'm unclear reading the documentation how to do that.  Any examples or documentation much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Every JSON response is a road map of the conversation. So if you take the related System + Context object from the response, you can feed it back in to get back an earlier response.

That is one way to approach it.

To capture the intent/entities within context variables you can do the following in your output node (advanced).

```
{
  "output": {},
  "context": {
    "lastIntent": "<? intents[0].intent ?>",
    "lastConfidence": "<? intents[0].confidence ?>",
    "lastEntity": "<? entities[0].value ?>"
  }
}
```

At the current time it will only work if you save it as a text value. So you can't do the following:

```
"confidence": <? intents[0].confidence ?>,
```

In your condition node you can do something like:

```
intents[0].intent == context.lastIntent
```

Comment: Thanks, Simon.  So far I've been trying to use just the api tool to develop the dialogs, with limited additional coding but as I develop the server side I'll be adding more info such as you suggested.  See my answer for an alternate approach that I was able to come up.  I'm not sure it's the best or ultimately final flow but it does work for now.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try out Simon's suggestion when i get to coding the app server, but for now I found a way using the API tool to do what I wanted.  Here's an image of the relevant dialog flow:

[image]

The user says "Read the ingredients" which triggers the #play_element + @recipeElement condition. Then if they say "Pause" Watson is aware that it refers to the @recipeElement condition.  Saying "Continue" or "Replay" also still refers to that same element. "Stop", however ends the loop.  Now I just have to figure out how to handle saying pause, continue or replay after they say stop - currently it goes back to the #play_element condition because the Anything Else condition doesn't seem to be working.